# Text to speech android for chinese

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

```
result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.CHINA);
if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            }
```

I have some text that are in English inside my string which I believe is the cause of the log message which says that the language is not supported.

My question is that is there a way to by pass this exception or should I try to eliminate all the English words on my string then perform the translation?

Also another question is "what other possible exceptions of failure to TextToSpeech?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT: this answer is obsolete. Android supports Chinese now.

Android does not support Chinese out of the box. The docs state:

> The TTS engine that ships with the Android platform supports a number
>   of languages: English, French, German, Italian and Spanish.

A Chinese engine might be available for download on the Market. Try the one called "SVOX Classic" - it supports downloadable voices for a large variety of languages.

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365792/japanese-tts-on-android).