# android TTS install language if not exist

Tags: android

i Try to use `JAPANESE` language on my Android 4 device.

```
int value = tts.setLanguage(Locale.JAPANESE);
```

but value is -2.

this is my code for checking

```
protected void check(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            switch (resultCode) {
            case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS:
                tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
                break;
            case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_BAD_DATA:
            case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_MISSING_DATA:
            case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_MISSING_VOLUME:
                Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installIntent);
                break;
            case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FAIL:
            default:
                Log.e(TAG, "Got a failure. TTS not available");
            }
        }
    }
```

and i want to install language if not exist. But app crashes. Is this correct wy ir what can i do? How to get japanese language?

Comment: There was similar questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365792/japanese-tts-on-android

However, I guess it does not help. Please write more - how your app is crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start your method by testing result code is equal to 0 and then have a swith on result code value (which you already know is equal to 0):

```
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        switch (resultCode) {
```

As written in your code, if language is not installed `tts` will not be initialized and any further reference to it will crash you application.

You can see the correct way to do it in [An introduction to Text-To-Speech in Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html)

Regards.

Comment: thank you. and if language is not supported can i install it? or is this just for basic google TTS or pico TTS.